# How can I have a hammer.js swipe event fire on a parent element but not general child element?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am using hammer.js 2.0

I have a container, that needs to have swipe events. However, that container has an element which is a carousel, that contains its own swipe vents. How can I have this swipe event fire everywhere *but* the carousel?

```
var self = this,
    hammerContainer = document.querySelector('section.content-wrapper'),
    carousel = document.querySelector('.image-gallery-carousel'),
    hammerOpts = {
      threshold: 4,
      velocity: .3
    },
    hammer = new Hammer(hammerContainer, hammerOpts);

Hammer.off(carousel, 'swipeleft swiperight', function () {
});

hammer.on('swipeleft', function (e) {
// do some other things
});
```

The `.off` method doesn't seem to work on my carousel. Hammer events are still ¿propagating? ¿bubbling?

It needs to not fire on *just* the carousel, but any children it may have, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I found to work involved getting jQuery involved. I don't feel like a a better person.

1. grab `event.target`
2. Use jQuery's `.parents()` method to grab all of my target's parents that would be of a given classname
3. Use an `if` statement to check the length of those parents, and if the length is 0, execute my swipe
4. Use the attribute selector to check for all instances and variations of the word carousel as a class name, e.g.: `[class*="carousel"]`

   ```
   var self = this,
     hammerContainer = document.querySelector('section.content-wrapper'),
     hammerOpts = {
       threshold: 4,
       velocity: .3
     },
     hammer = new Hammer(hammerContainer, hammerOpts);

     hammer.on('swiperight', function (e) {
       if (!$(e.target).parents('[class*="carousel"]').length) {
        //do swipey things   
       }
     });
   ```

I feel like event propagation should be a thing I'd be able to do. Like, invoking `e.stopPropagation()`.

Someone, *anyone*, please show me a better way.